# Python- complete names of US states given the first four characters?

Tags: python

I have a list of US states with the first four/five characters- i.e. Massachusetts would be "Mass" or "Massa", California would be "Calif" or "Cali," or an abbreviation such as "N.J." or "N.Y." and I need the full name of the state. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean it should... guess?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of regular expressions and testing cases to fill the correct state name, but I'm not sure how to approach this. I would hope that the solution is not guessing or manual fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a dict that maps all of the abbreviations to the full names.

It looks like you actually have three kinds of abbreviations. But that's not a problem; just separately generate dictionaries for all three kinds, then merge them together with `update`.

```
state_abbrev = {state[:4]: state for state in states}
state_abbrev.update({state[:5]: state for state in states})
state_abbrev.update({'.'.join(filter(str.isupper, state))+'.': state 
                     for state in states})
```

The last one may be a bit too overly-clever, so let me break it down to explain it:

```
>>> state = 'New York'
>>> caps = filter(str.isupper, state)
>>> caps
['N', 'Y']
>>> '.'.join(caps)
'N.Y'
>>> '.'.join(caps) + '.'
'N.Y.'
```

There are some ambiguities here, but they're inherent in your problem:

- Mississippi and Missouri have the same four-letter prefixes. So, `Miss` is going to map to one of them arbitrarily. New Mexico, New Jersey, and New York have these same problem. And North Dakota vs. North Carolina and their Southern neighbors even have the same five-letter prefixes.
- Many one-word state names have the same abbreviation: Maine, Massachusetts, Mississippi, Missouri, Minnesota, and Michigan are all `M.`, so that's going to map to one of those arbitrarily.

Hopefully, none of these ambiguous prefixes or abbreviations will ever come up in your code, so the fact that they get mapped to something arbitrary will never matter. If you want to instead raise an error in those cases, it's not too hard to add a rule that blocks any ambiguous entries, or one that requires two words for an abbreviation, or… whatever it is you want to add.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is perfectly clear.

Comment: @user2631296: I would strongly suggest that you print out the (sorted) dictionary and make sure all of the mappings make sense. The fact that I didn't find any cases where my overly-clever hack gets it wrong doesn't prove there isn't one just as bad as the Mississippi/Missouri thing in falsetru's 4-letter trick, it just proves that I didn't find one. :)

Comment: Thanks. I did- there were some corner cases, but I checked that the "full" state names produced were correct.

Answer (score 3):

Make a dictionary that map 4 characters state names to complete names.

```
>>> complete_names = 'Massachusetts', 'California', 'New York', 'New Jersey',
>>> states = {state[:4]: state for state in complete_names}
>>> states.update({''.join(c[0] + '.' for c in state.split()): state for state in complete_names} )
>>> states['Mass']
'Massachusetts'
>>> states['Cali']
'California'
>>> states['N.Y.']
'New York'
```

If the name is longer than 4 characters, slice it to 4 characters.

```
>>> states['Calif']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Calif'
>>> states['Calif'[:4]]
'California'
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing the same thing, when I noticed that the description says "four/five characters", and also says "or an abbreviation such as N.J.". So you need something more complicated than this dict comprehension.

Comment: Yes. The data was scraped from a webpage and the cleaning process is becoming a bit messy and I'm stuck on this part.

Comment: Also, the "slice it to 4 characters" idea is a neat trick, but there are some states that are ambiguous to 4 characters but not to 5 (`'Missi'` vs. `'Misso'`, all the `'New'` states). Then again, there are also states that are ambiguous to 5 characters (the two `'North'` and `'South'` pairs), and I have no idea what he wants to do with those…

Answer (score 1):

Let me present a 3rd alternative You can have a dictionary of full state names to their abbreviations.

```
>>> states = { "Georgia" : "GA", "New Jersey": "NJ"}
```

You can then use regular expression to extract letters from the raw data you are scraping. You will now have to check whether the extracted data is in the dictionary key, or is the value of the key itself.

```
>>> import re
>>> rawState = "N.J."
>>> toFind = "".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", rawState))
>>> for state in states:
...     if toFind in state or toFind in states[state]:
...             print state
... 
New Jersey
```

Same example but different `rawState`:

```
>>> rawState = "Georg"
>>> toFind = "".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", rawState))
>>> for state in states:
...     if toFind in state or toFind in states[state]:
...             print state
... 
Georgia
```

In hindsight, I should have made it a function like `findState(rawState)`.

Comment: You're adding more data than he's asked for (e.g., there's no indication he wants to find `"GA"`), and this also adds ambiguities that will cause problems, not to mention that you've doubled his data-entry requirements.

Comment: Well, he said abbreviation, so I think `GA` would fall under that category. What problems specifically will this cause?

Comment: The examples of abbreviations he gave are `"N.J."` and `"N.Y."`—which are not the two-letter post office abbreviations assigned to each state, but standard English-language abbreviations, with the first letter of each word with a `.` after it.

Comment: Actually, I think you get lucky here. If you did the searches case-insensitively, the fact that, e.g., `NE` is part of `Nevada` would be a problem. If you included the provinces of Canada along with the states of the US, you'd have collisions between English-language abbreviations and official abbreviations. With exactly the data set you have, I don't think either of these problems comes up. But I'd want to verify it. And, better, I'd want to not _have_ to verify it, and not have to count on getting lucky. Just don't add the extra information, and there are fewer things to check.

Comment: That's right, you are correct. `NE` is in `Nevada` and a case insensitive search would absolutely be unreliable with this solution. I do make certain big assumptions which I should not have. However, the solution is fairly simple and will work if only US states are to be considered.

Comment: I think this is the way to go: Build a table.  After all, how often does the USA add new states?

Comment: @slider: Well, all three of us made assumptions, and both you and I happened to get lucky, while falsetru happened not to… I _tried_ to find, test, and explain all of the assumptions I made, but I easily might have missed one.

Comment: @dstromberg: Sure, DC and Puerto Rico statehood are obviously pipe dreams that will never come true, but how long do you think Canada's going to survive as an independent country? ;)